# " XXX not declared in this scope"¿Dónde declarar un atributo para declararlo en el ámbito correcto?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de modelar el estado en el que estaríamos y los movimientos que podemos hacer en un árbol binario como el siguiente:

```
               10
             /    \
            6      14
           / \    /  \
          5   8  11  18
```

Utilizo el código dado por Alex Allain [aquí](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html). Entonces he hecho el siguiente código:

```
#define NULL 0
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int key_value;
  node *left;
  node *right;
};

//es una tabula de movimientos posibles. Toma un nodo y un nodo de un nodo dado en una Junta
struct Move{
        vector<node> moves[2];
};

// Muestra el estado actual de un juego
class Board{

    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();

        Board(btree,node);
        Move getLegalMoves(node); //Número de movimientos que se pueden realizar desde la posición actual
        int legalMoves(Move); //movimientos que se pueden realizar desde la posición actual

    private:
        //member variables
        int length;
        int score;
        node n; // Dónde estamos en el momento de la junta


};

Board::Board(btree b, node n){
    length = NULL; 

    score = n.key_value; //DONE? : numero del  node actual 
    Move moves[2];
    if(n->*left != NULL)
        moves[0] = n->*left;//tabula de las posiciones izquierda y derecha del estado actual
        moves[1] = n->*right;

};
```

Pero me contesto el compilador lo siguiente :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/NestedMonteCarlo/NestedForBinaryTrees$ g++ main.cpp -o NestedMonteCarlo
main.cpp: In constructor ‘Board::Board(btree, node)’:
main.cpp:164:9: error: ‘left’ was not declared in this scope
  if(n->*left != NULL)
         ^
main.cpp:166:18: error: ‘right’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[1] = n->*right;
                  ^
main.cpp: In member function ‘int Board::legalMoves(Move)’:
main.cpp:173:9: error: ‘left’ was not declared in this scope
  if(n->*left != NULL){// wrong we have to take move into account
         ^
main.cpp: In member function ‘Move Board::getLegalMoves(node)’:
main.cpp:184:9: error: ‘left’ was not declared in this scope
  if(n->*left != NULL)
         ^
main.cpp:185:3: error: ‘moves’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[0] = n->*left;//DONE? array of the left and right positions from curren
   ^
main.cpp:186:3: error: ‘moves’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[1] = n->*right;
   ^
main.cpp:186:18: error: ‘right’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[1] = n->*right;
...
```

Sin embargo, pensé que me aseguraba de que estuviese dentro del alcance al escribir en un `node n` en la partida privada de la clase para mostrar dónde estamos en el árbol binario

El código completo esta en un [repositorio GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/NestedMonteCarloForBinaryTrees).

Sirve para saber donde puedo ir o cuantas posibilidades tengo desde un nodo. Por ejemplo desde `14` tenemos dos posibilidades pero desde `11` tenemos 0.

```
// gives the number of leaves we can play : either 2 or 0 in the binary-tree case.
int Board::legalMoves(Move moves){
    //If there is leaves there is at least two moves.
    if(n.left != NULL){// wrong we have to take move into account
        return 2;   
    }//otherwise there is no possibilities
    else{
        return 0;
    }

};

// gives the number of leaves we can play : either 2 or 0 in the binary-tree case.
Move Board::getLegalMoves(node n){
    if(n.left != NULL)
        moves[0] = n.left;//DONE? array of the left and right positions from current state  //node *left; and node *right;
        moves[1] = n.right;
};
```

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres que entendamos el error si no muestras el código que genera el error? (si, ya veo el enlace a GitHub, pero no tengo acceso a esa página). Por favor, comparte tu `main`.

Comment: intenta poner en tu constructor el parametro `node* n` y no `node n`, al intentar llamar a los nodos q apunta simplemente al `n->left`

Answer (score 0):

El compilador te está marcando error en dos métodos que no publicaste en la pregunta, sin embargo, en el constructor tambein te está marcando que left y right no se declararon en este ámbito y me parece que es porque lo que buscas hacer con n->*left o n->*right es obtener el valor de lo que apunta la direccion de memoria n->left y n->right, pero esa no es la forma de obtener un valor apuntado por un puntero. 
Si lo que quieres es obtener lo que hay en la direccion n->left o n->right, intenta usar *(n->left) o *(n->right), ahora otra cosa que ví en tu código es que estas definiendo la constante NULL manualmente, constante que ya viene definida en la cabecera "< cstdio >" y efectivamente, tambien tiene un valor de 0, si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Agregué el repositorio con el código completo y el codigo para el arbol binario que utiliso

Answer (score 0):

En la función, `n` no es un puntero:

```
Board::Board(btree b, node n)
//                    ^^^^^^
```

Luego esta línea está mal:

```
if(n->*left != NULL)
```

Ya que **no puedes** usar el operador `->` en elementos que no sean punteros. Debes usar `.`:

```
if(n.left != NULL)
```

Además no tiene sentido usar el asterisco por dos razones:

- Donde lo estás poniendo no tiene ningún sentido. Si quieres acceder a la memoria de `left` tienes que hacerlo así:

  ```
  // opcion 1
  *n.left

  // opcion 2
  *(n.left)
  ```
- Tu intención aquí no es acceder a la memoria de `left` sino verificar dicha posición de memoria.

En lo que respecta a las otras dos líneas, lo explicado hasta la fecha es aplicable... pero tienen más errores:

```
moves[0] = n->*left;
```

`moves` es un array de dos posiciones de tipo `Move`... y `Move` es una estructura que contiene un vector de tipo `node`. No existe ningúna conversión posible entre `node` y `Move`, luego esa asignación va a dar un error de compilación.

En este punto no me quedan nada claras tus intenciones... pero el hecho de que en cada objeto de tipo `Move` se pueden almacenar dos `node` me hace pensar que tu intención tal vez haya sido esta:

```
moves[0].moves[0] = *n.left;
moves[0].moves[1] = *n.right;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para tu ayuda ! Mis intenciones son almacenar los nodos izquierdo y derecho, `left` y `right` a los que puedo acceder desde el nodo `n`. Es por decir : Move es una estructura que contiene un vector de nodos a la que puedo ir desde el nodo `n`. Entonces no entiendo qué representa `moves[0] .moves [0] = * n.left` y
`moves[0] .moves [1] = * n.right;`

Comment: @Marine1 fijate que `Moves` es una estructura que tiene un unico miembro llamado `moves`. El primer `moves` es la variable de tipo `Moves`, mientras que el segundo es la variable miembro. Por lo que dices da la impresión de que lo que realmente quieres hacer se consigue cambiando `Moves moves[2];` por `vector<node> moves[2];`

Comment: Muchas gracias, entonces es necesario cambiar cosas en al asignar los nodos a la derecha y a la izquierda `moves[0] = *n.left;` y `moves[1] = *n.right;`? Por lo momento da una error `no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Move’ and ‘node*’)
   moves[0] = n.left;`

Comment: @Marine1 si te interesa guardar una copia de los nodos sí... pero como te digo depende de lo que necesites almacenar

Comment: los nodos izquierdo y derecho desde un nodo dado, entonces el cambio necesario hacer `moves[0].moves[0] = *n.left;` para obtener la variable miembro que esta en un variable `Moves` despues utilsar vectores de node ?

Comment: @Marine1 lo que consigues con eso es una copia del nodo... que no es lo mismo que una copia del puntero... ignoro qué quieres hacer con esa información, luego no me es posible decirte si lo que necesitas es una copia del puntero o del nodo

Comment: Con esa información quiero dar con `int legalMoves(Moves move)` cuantos `moves` tenemos desde un nodo